# Using gsub to add space between specific area with upper and lower case, not all upper and lower case?

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to change some of my column characters and add a space between certain words. I have scowered stackoverflow, and I tried using these codes

```
df$Method_Group = gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", " ", df$Method_Group)
df$Method_Group = gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2 ", df$Method_Group)
df$Method_Group = gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", ".", df$Method_Group)
```

but it either removes some of my words, or adds spaces in the wrong places.

Essentially I want a space between `Animal` and `Borne` and I want a space between `No` and `Receiver`. Here is a sample of my dataframe

```
df = structure(list(Theme = c("Adult migration", "Adult migration", 
"Adult migration", "Adult migration", "Adult migration", "Aquaculture", 
"Aquaculture", "Artificial Reefs", "Attributing behaviours to movement", 
"Attributing behaviours to movement", "Attributing behaviours to movement", 
"Attributing behaviours to movement", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Co_existence", "Co_existence", 
"Co_existence", "Co_existence", "Commercial species", "Commercial species", 
"Commercial species", "Commercial species", "Community structuring", 
"Community structuring", "Cooperative Behaviour", "Demographics"
), Tracking_Group = c(Animalborne_Satellite_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Stationary_Radio = "NoReceiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Acoustic_Radio_PIT = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Controlled_Acoustic = "Receiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Stationary_Radio_PIT = "Receiver", BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite = "Both", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Satellite_Archival = "NoReceiver", Controlled_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Stationary_Archival = "NoReceiver", Stationary_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Stationary_Satellite = "NoReceiver", Animalborne_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Animalborne_Acoustic_Archival = "Receiver", BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", Controlled_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Controlled_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic_Archival = "Receiver", BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite = "Both"), Combination = c("Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", 
"Stationary_Radio", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic_Radio_PIT", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Controlled_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Radio_PIT", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Controlled_Archival", 
"Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", "Stationary_Satellite", 
"Animalborne_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Acoustic_Archival", "BRUV_Acoustic", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Archival", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "BRUV_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite"
), Total_Publications = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Topic = c("Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Landuse Management", 
"Conservation Methods", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use"
), Method_Group = c("Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Stationary_NoReceiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Controlled_Receiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "BRUV_Both", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Controlled_NoReceiver", "Stationary_NoReceiver", 
"Stationary_NoReceiver", "Stationary_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_Receiver", 
"Animalborne_Receiver", "BRUV_Receiver", "BRUV_Receiver", "Controlled_Receiver", 
"Controlled_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", 
"Stationary_NoReceiver", "BRUV_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "BRUV_Receiver", "BRUV_Receiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"BRUV_Both")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(Theme = c("Adult migration", 
"Adult migration", "Adult migration", "Adult migration", "Aquaculture", 
"Aquaculture", "Artificial Reefs", "Attributing behaviours to movement", 
"Attributing behaviours to movement", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Behavioural states and adaptations", "Behavioural states and adaptations", 
"Co_existence", "Co_existence", "Commercial species", "Commercial species", 
"Commercial species", "Commercial species", "Community structuring", 
"Cooperative Behaviour", "Demographics"), Topic = c("Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Fisheries Managemenet", "Landuse Management", "Conservation Methods", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use"
), Tracking_Group = c(Animalborne_Satellite_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Stationary_Radio = "NoReceiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic_Radio_PIT = "Receiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Controlled_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", Stationary_Radio_PIT = "Receiver", 
BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite = "Both", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Satellite_Archival = "NoReceiver", Controlled_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Stationary_Archival = "NoReceiver", Stationary_Satellite = "NoReceiver", 
Animalborne_Acoustic = "Receiver", Animalborne_Acoustic_Archival = "Receiver", 
BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", Controlled_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Archival = "NoReceiver", 
BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", Stationary_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Stationary_Acoustic_Archival = "Receiver", BRUV_Acoustic = "Receiver", 
Animalborne_Archival = "NoReceiver", BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite = "Both"
), Combination = c("Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Stationary_Radio", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic_Radio_PIT", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Stationary_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Stationary_Radio_PIT", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite", "Animalborne_Archival", 
"Animalborne_Satellite_Archival", "Controlled_Archival", "Stationary_Archival", 
"Stationary_Satellite", "Animalborne_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Acoustic_Archival", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "Controlled_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", 
"Animalborne_Archival", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Archival", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic", "Stationary_Acoustic_Archival", 
"BRUV_Acoustic", "Animalborne_Archival", "BRUV_Acoustic_Satellite"
), Method_Group = c("Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Stationary_NoReceiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "Controlled_Receiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Stationary_Receiver", "BRUV_Both", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Controlled_NoReceiver", "Stationary_NoReceiver", 
"Stationary_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_Receiver", "Animalborne_Receiver", 
"BRUV_Receiver", "Controlled_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", 
"Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_NoReceiver", 
"BRUV_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", "Stationary_Receiver", 
"BRUV_Receiver", "Animalborne_NoReceiver", "BRUV_Both"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3:4, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9:11, 12L, 13L, 14:23, 24L, 
    25L, 26:27, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31:32, 33:34, 35:38, 39:40, 41:42, 
    43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47:48, 49L, 50L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -29L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: borne is not capitalized in your example, so you need to make it a special case, otherwise you can simplify and just use a lower case followed by uppercase: `gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=Animal)(?=borne)', ' ', 'Animalborne_NoReceiver', perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Using that code removes all the other values except for animal borne and no receiver

Comment: I don't know what you mean; in my quick test, the unique set of values changed is `list(a = c("Animalborne_NoReceiver", "Stationary_NoReceiver", "Controlled_NoReceiver", "Animalborne_Receiver"), b = c("Animal borne_No Receiver", "Stationary_No Receiver", "Controlled_No Receiver", "Animal borne_Receiver"))`, all other values are unaffected.

Comment: ```df$Method_Group = gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=Animal)(?=borne)', ' ', 'Animalborne_NoReceiver', perl = TRUE) ``` turns the entire column into ```Animal borne + No Receiver```

Comment: The obligatory arguments for `gsub` are `gsub(pattern, replacement, x)` where `x` is the data you want to apply it on. Use `gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=Animal)(?=borne)', ' ', df$Method_Group, perl = TRUE)`.

Comment: Kristen Cyr, rawr's recommendation in the comment might have been a little lazy (I do that frequently as well): the third argument in that comment is `'Animalborne_NoReceiver'` but should be `df$Method_Group`. Doing it like that in a comment is a real-brief self-contained code expression, intending for your takeaway to be the regex pattern (and replacement). You might be suspicious on code recommendations that don't reference your real `df` frame :-)